'Stubborn' DVD, unreadable with various products
I have a DVD that I want to play. I have attempted to play it with VLC, PotPlayer, MPC-BE and one or two other products.
No luck.
Is there something else that I could try that takes a particularly careful approach to reading DVDs, or there an approach I might take to getting the contents in a form that would enable me to dissect out any bad spots?

Is the DVD region-coded for a region different than your drive is coded?

@JeffZeitlin: Thanks, Jeff. I can play about three minutes of the first title with each player, then the player quits.
